# Riemann surface $w^3= z^2(z^2-1)$

Tags: riemann-surfaces

How to find the chart around $(0,0)$ of $\{(z,w)\in\mathbb C\times \mathbb C: w^3= z^2(z^2-1)\}$? For $f(z,w)= w^3-z^2(z^2-1)$, in this case both $\frac{\partial f(z,w)}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial f(z,w)}{\partial w}$ at $(0,0)$ vanishes.   So the projection map does not become a chart—any hint to proceed with this?

Comment: Note that zero set of a  smooth affine plane curves form a Riemann surface. In this case at $(0,0) $ this not smooth